# FLOT data from MySQL via PHP?

Tags: mysql, flot

Good afternoon, I have looked at the FLOT website examples and googled but just cannot find anywhere with detailed steps on how to pull data from MySQL into FLOT.

Currently I have a php page with a recordset that stores all records from a mysql table, columns are date, user & cost. Do I need to create a data table to display all these records in the page?

When above is sorted how would I call that data into FLOT, I know its probably very obvious to any develiopers out there but I just cant find the info today.

Thanks for any help/pointers offered.

Answer (score 1):

Look the AJAX example in the flot [documentation](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html).

Essentially the steps are:

1.) Pull from database.

2.) Place data in PHP key/value array of form:

```
$dataSet1 = Array();
$dataSet1['label'] = 'Customer 1';
$dataSet1['data'] = Array(Array(1,1),Array(2,2)); // an array of arrays of point pairs

$dataSet2 = Array();
$dataSet2['label'] = 'Customer 2';
$dataSet2['data'] = Array(Array(3,3),Array(4,5)); // an array of arrays of point pairs

$returnArray = Array($dataSet1, $dataSet2);
```

3.) Back in your javascript, get this json encoded string as JS variable:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

4.) Back in your javascript, call the flot plot method with that data variable:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer, sorry for delay had to resolve other issues with some servers. I have =checked the ajx demo but cannot for the life of me work out where the json data is coming from or how its created? Thats where I am stuck. All I have managed so far is to create a test.php page which contains a recordset and output table in body that display records. I understand I need to get this to jsaon but that's where I am baffled?

Comment: @gary, in the linked example they are returning the JSON from a file on the server, this is not quite what you want.  You need to loop your result set and create the format FLOT expects.  This is what I describe in step 2 above.  Step 3 shows you then how to have PHP encode your Arrays in JSON.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks again for your time. I'm afraid I just don't understand the steps, I'm a server admin in real life tasked with this project as no developers left to assist [credit crunch UK]!

I have been searching endlessly for a sample download demo of Mysql/php/JSON & FLOT working together, once I see it in real life I tend to be able to adapt better. 

Anyway thanks again n for your time, was appreciated.