# Structure of PHP array needed for creation of Flot chart (with JSON)

Tags: php, json, flot

I need to create chart using Flot chart library, using PHP JSON functions (ie. json_encode).

Problem is that I don't understand structure of PHP array that have to be encoded to create proper JS array for generating Flot charts.

Chart needs to have several lines, with different colors.

Can somebody help me with some example of proper PHP array for this kind.

I have tried (without success) to implement next example:

[FLOT data from MySQL via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161785/flot-data-from-mysql-via-php)

Problem with it is that I'm getting Object that I don't know how to implement in my script:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'post', 
        dataType: "json", 
        url:'/stocks/index/',
        success: function(r) {
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), [
                {data:(r)}
            ] )
        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**: php code used to generate JSON array looks like this:

```
$dataSet1 = array();
$dataSet1['label'] = 'Customer 1';
$dataSet1['data'] = array(array(1,1),array(2,2)); // an array of arrays of point pairs

$dataSet2 = array();
$dataSet2['label'] = 'Customer 2';
$dataSet2['data'] = array(array(3,3),array(4,5)); // an array of arrays of point pairs

$flots = array($dataSet1, $dataSet2);
return json_encode($flots);
```

Comment: show your PHP code too.. P.S. the responde of you json is a javascript object so [{}] is not needed :)

Comment: it's in updated part of my message

Comment: dont return json_encode .. echo it ;)

Comment: i tried that before, no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$dataSet1 = array();
$dataSet1['label'] = 'Customer 1';
$dataSet1['data'] = array(array(1,1),array(2,2)); // an array of arrays of point pairs

$dataSet2 = array();
$dataSet2['label'] = 'Customer 2';
$dataSet2['data'] = array(array(3,3),array(4,5)); // an array of arrays of point pairs

$flots = array($dataSet1, $dataSet2);
echo json_encode($flots);
```

php file..

and

```
$.ajax({
        type:'post', 
        dataType: "json", 
        url:'/stocks/index/',
        success: function(data) {
            $.plot($("#placeholder"),  data );
        }
    });
```